# Can FullCalendar use multiple ICS urls?

Tags: fullcalendar, icalendar

I know FullCalendar can use multiple sources.  I am able to get a great render using one ICS url.  Is it possible to use multiple ICS files?

Comment: Yes, why not? Have you tried? Was there a problem? The ICS source is an event source like any other. You can specify multiple event sources in the config - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have been trying all day.  Been through the documentation many times.  ICS is not quite like any other event source as it requires the plugin: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/icalendar.  The info on the page you posted talks about any number of sources being " event arrays, functions, JSON feed URLs, or full-out Event Source Objects" but it doesn't mention anywhere about multiple ICS files.

Comment: That sounds like an oversight. You could raise a documentation bug with the fullcalendar team. Google calendar sources are also not mentioned in that list.

Answer (score 1):

I just got it!  It was the syntax that I couldn't get right....

```
   eventSources: [ 
      {
         url: "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays/england-and-wales.ics",
         format: "ics",
      },
      {
         url: "https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays/england-and-wales.ics", 
         format: "ics",
      }
    ]
```